# $n^k\alpha^n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $k \geq 1$ and $0 < \alpha < 1$, I have to prove that $n^k\alpha^n \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$. Intuitively, I think I have to prove that $\alpha^n$ is going faster to $0$ than $n^k$ is going to $\infty$ when $n \to \infty$. I think I have to use the binomial theorem, but it is very unclear right now. Can you give me a hint how to solve this?

**Note:** I can't use the ratio test here.

Comment: Intuitively, you can see what happens to each of the two terms if you double $n$. Along with a monotonicity argument, that's enough to conclude.

Comment: @Arthur You mean to each of the to **factors** (not terms), right?

Comment: Well, sure, yes, that. I'm not always too strict about it. Maybe I ought to be.

Comment: @Arthur Can you explain a bit more your argument as a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

What about the good old ratio test?
$$\frac{(n+1)^k\alpha^{n+1}}{n^k\alpha^n}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^k\cdot\alpha\to\alpha<1 $$

After your edit:

What about the good old root test?

$$(n^k\alpha^n)^\frac{1}{n}=\alpha\cdot n^\frac{k}{n}\to\alpha<1$$

Even if you can't use that, see this as the values $f(n)$ for $f(x)=x^k\cdot \alpha^x$ and use L' Hospital rule to compute the limit of $f$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Note what happens to $n^k$ and $\alpha^n$ if you double $n$:

- $n^k$ gets multiplied by $2^k$
- $\alpha^n$ gets squared

Once $n$ is large enough that $\alpha^n<2^{-k}$, the product $n^k\alpha^n$ clearly decreases as you double $n$. And the next time you double $n$ the product decreases even more. And next time, more.

Noting that $n^k$ and $\alpha^n$ are both monotonous, while it doesn't by itself show that the product is monotonous, does let you bound the product and show that it goes to $0$.

Comment: Can you make a full rigorous proof using that principle? I am curious to see you handle this